# Valid yml file syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

My rails app won't start up. I suspect it's because there's an initializer that reads from a yml file and the yml file is broken. Is this valid yml?

```
development:
  token: secret
production: &default
  invite_token_secret: <%= ENV["TOKEN_SECRET"] %>
staging:
  <<: *default
```

I sometimes see figaro files use that erb-like syntax. Is that allowed in a standard yml file though?

Comment: is it a yml or yml.erb ?

Comment: It's just a .yml file.

Comment: It is valid .yml file, but may not 'valid' as expected. `<%= ENV["TOKEN_SECRET"] %>` is ERb syntax that you inject variable, if you just use the original text as yaml text, the secret would be `<%= ENV["TOKEN_SECRET"] %>` itself. Is that what you want ?

Comment: which environment is it broken? production,staging or development?